# Is Selenium can do it?

Tags: selenium, testing, web

I have no experience with testing web page in SeleniumHD and I would start soon. 
I have a website http://ffmama.azurewebsites.net/Home/About
On it is a chart which time the tests need to enter data.
This is time-consuming and tiring job. 
I thought to SeleniunHD - but is it able to do? 
- Enter data into multiple table cells, eg from an external file or a spreadsheet, 
- To wait for a response from the server 
- Save the result of the work file
 
Please answer the questions
Thank you and best regards

Comment: Hi may i know what you mean by SeleniumHD as far as i know there are no SeleniumHD automation tool.

Comment: Suppose you mean `Selenium WD`... Yes. This is an answer for your question. You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. I need Selenium WD.
Do you have any experience? how to start, make first step to fill cells automatically?

> The primary new feature in Selenium 2.0 is the integration of the
>   WebDriver API. WebDriver is designed to provide a simpler, more
>   concise programming interface in addition to addressing some
>   limitations in the Selenium-RC API. Selenium-WebDriver was developed
>   to better support dynamic web pages where elements of a page may
>   change without the page itself being reloaded. WebDriver’s goal is to
>   supply a well-designed object-oriented API that provides improved
>   support for modern advanced web-app testing problems.

Comment: first step is to learn programming language :) `Selenium` as far as I know supports `Ruby`, `Python`, `Java`, `C#` ...